# What is Reset(handle,1)?

Tags: delphi

I came across this code of Reset(elfhandle,1) and I don't know what the second input of 1 does. What does the second input of Reset specify?

Comment: (almost -1) - F1 key not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second parameter in the  [`System.Reset`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.Reset) function is the record size to be read.

You can find more info in the [Delphi online help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.Reset).

> RecSize is an optional expression that can be specified only if F is
>   an untyped file. If F is an untyped file, RecSize specifies the record
>   size to be used in data transfers. If RecSize is omitted, a default
>   record size of 128 bytes is assumed.